# Ransack: finding record without a :has_one assoc

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, ransack

Given a ModelA which has_one ModelB.

What should I write if I want to add a checkbox in the ModelA form to filter the results to only show ModelsA who are NOT associated with ModelB.

I tried:

```
f.check_box :modelb_null, {}, true, nil
```

and

```
f.check_box :modelb_id_null, {}, true, nil
```

without success.

Answer (score 0):

You do need to call a specific field on the association, not just the model name, and ID makes the most sense as per your second attempt.

I got this working using the `blank` predicate:

`f.check_box :modelb_id_blank, {}, true, nil`